# Limit Firebase authentication to session

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to implement a "Keep me signed-in" check box when the user signs-in. If the checkbox is checked then the user should remain signed-in until they explicitly sign-out. If not checked, the user should only remain signed-in until they close the app.

The Flutter Firebase Authentication package doesn't have a method for configuring the authentication duration, or at least I've not found a method.

I've tried to listen for when the app is shutting down using the WidgetsBindingObserver's didChangeAppLifecycleState(..) method's AppLifecycleState.detached state. I can see the signOut() method called, but despite this the user remains signed-in the next time they launch the app. I'm not surprised given that the app is in the middle of exiting.

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if( state == AppLifecycleState.detached ){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Am I missing any good options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Firebase Authentication SDKs persist the authentication state to local storage, and then restore it from there when the app restarts.

If you want the state to not be persisted, you can configure that when the app starts by calling:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.setPersistence(Persistence.NONE);
```

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [persisting authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#persisting-authentication-state).

Comment: It's notable that setPersistence(..) is only supported on web. From doc: "on native platforms an UnimplementedError will be thrown"

Answer (score 0):

That's because signOut() returns a Future. So you'll have to `await` it. So, suppose you have a function `userSignOut`.

```
Future<void> userSignOut() => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

And you use it on a button...

```
IconButton(
  icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
  onPressed: () async {
    await userSignOut();
  },
)
```

This should solve your issue. If it still doesn't work, provide more relevant code.